# MQ System w/ brokers - Any way to examine everything

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I have inherited an IMB MQ (V6) system that has multiple brokers.  Is there a way to explore everything succinctly ?

i.e.  I know what queue managers are running, so without "runmqsc"ing each and every manager, how can i find broker names, listeners, etc ?

There is the Explorer running but again points to knowing the manager and port to have it connect successfully.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by multiple brokers - are you talking about IBM integration bus (previous known as WebSphere message broker) ?

Comment: Yep. Need to go back to Version 6, and no, there is no option to upgrade.  So for example, i have a queue manager A, B, C and D.  A port scan shows  8 ports listening.  QM A has a listener on port 1414, a broker and a listener on port 1415.  What i would like to do is to "dump" the whole configuration so I can find out what's the broker on B and it's listener port, etc.    Maintenance contract termed last year and current support staff unavailable for the foreseeable future.  No documentation and a toolkit that is 1/2 broken.  Scotty i need warp power in 20 minutes or we're all dead.

Comment: I'm assuming your qmgrs A B C & D are on different servers?  Not sure there is a way to "dump" everything from the distributed systems.  Maybe someone from broker team can give you more info.

Comment: Everything is on a single server and unfortunately, there is no more broker team.  I'm the developer w/ the most experience w/ MQ which means i can make apps talk to MQ but never really admin'd a box.

Answer (score 1):

For MQ, the dmpmqcfg command can be useful to output your configuration info to a file.

For the broker, try the mqsilist command to list installed brokers and their associated resources.

this webpage may be of help to you:
Performing health checks for WebSphere Message Broker 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0801_cui/0801_cui.html

Comment: mqsireportproperties BROKER -r -o AllReportableEntityNames -c AllTypes      does dump a lot so it's close to what i need.

Answer (score 0):

To work out which queue managers are running on your machine, use the`dspmq` command. Then you'll know each queue manager and can `runmqsc` to each one, or point MQ Explorer to each one, or whatever you need to do next.